# Featherlight input without submit

Tags: jquery, input

I have a featherlight popup box asking for a subset of dates. I do not want a Save button on the featherlight box, but the input values should be saved and then submitted using the Save button on the main page. How can i accomplish this?

```
<div class="featherlight-content">
  <div class="lightbox featherlight-inner" id="mylightbox">
Exercise Dates
  <br>
  <br>
    <input type="date" id="ex1" name="ex1" value="<?php echo $ex1 ?>" style="width: 120px"; padding: 5 5 5 0 ><br>
    <input type="date" id="ex2" name="ex2" value="<?php echo $ex2 ?>" style="width: 120px"; padding: 5 5 5 0 ><br>
    <input type="date" id="ex3" name="ex3" value="<?php echo $ex3 ?>" style="width: 120px"; padding: 5 5 5 0 ><br>
    <input type="date" id="ex4" name="ex4" value="<?php echo $ex4 ?>" style="width: 120px"; padding: 5 5 5 0 ><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check in featherlight documentation?

Comment: Yes, but i did not find anything in regards to this..

Comment: can you share it in fiddle? along with your js code